# internal link to part of html page not working

Tags: html, hyperlink, laravel-8, anchor

I can not figure why internal link to a section in an html page are not working... what am I missing?  I am working in Laravel and that might be the problem...

On the top of the page, I have:

```
<p>go to <a href="blog/79#maps">maps of our itinerary</a>)</p>
```

And at the bottom (I also tried name & id alone)

```
<p><a id="maps" name="maps"></a></p>
```

You can see it on my [blog](https://www.paulgodard.com/blog/79).  When I click on the map link, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your href.

To call the an anchor you should not include the URL you are in but rather just the ID of the anchor you want to navigate to.

Change to this:

```
<a href="#maps">maps of our itinerary</a>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="#maps">Go to Maps</a>
    <div style="height: 500px;"></div>
    <h1 id="maps">
      This is a static template, there is no bundler or bundling involved!
    </h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Also, as pointed out above you should not have two IDs with the same key. However this would still work, he would just assume the first ID found so your anchor not working is due to a malformed href and not duplicated IDs.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="#maps">Go to Maps</a>
    <div style="height: 500px;"></div>
    <h1 id="maps">
      ID #1
    </h1>
    <div style="height: 500px;"></div>
    <h1 id="maps">
      ID #2
    </h1>
  </body>
  
</html>
```

Hope this helps.

**Edit 2**

After some further research, I've noticed you are using a  URL tag on your .
Since your base URL is the homepage `<base href="https://www.paulgodard.com" />` the Browser search for #maps in your homepage causing this redirection. I don't see why one should use a base URL tag in HTML since all relative URLs will always be relative to the homepage.

Unless there's a specific reason to add this tag removing it will solve the problem for all anchors.

Comment: Thank you for your time to explain.  At first I did not realise that the duplicated anchor was due to the 2 sets of content for different viewports.  I have temporary removed one and as you suggested remove the page name before the # in the href (which I had tried before) but that does not work.  My blog has been updated but it does not work.  Maybe it is due to Laravel which wrongly interprets the internal link?  Any idea?

Comment: Ok got you, after some digging I relized you are using a tag like this <base href="https://www.paulgodard.com" /> in your code. This makes the Browser go look for your anchor at the homepage therefore it refreshes. Also to answer you laravel question, no, the anchors are used by the browser. So remove that <base> tag from your HTML code and I'm sure it will work.
I've been coding for more than 10 years and I didn't even know that tag existed, unless you added it there for a specific reason, I'm sure you don't need it.

Comment: YES indeed...it works.  Honestly I am not sure why I have added the base url tag... a few years back when I started using Laravel.  I will check across the site if it has no side effect... And thank you!

Comment: Anytime. Happy new year.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need the base url tag.  The reason is that I can not do a "normal" installation of Laravel in the public folder.  By defining the base url in that way, i could put all the Laravel system & php files in the public_html root and keep the assets in the public folder.  Bottom line, I have to keep it and find a way around for the #link... any idea?

Comment: I found a way to get the internal link to work as an absolute url together with the base url... and also removed the second instance of the same id

Comment: Hey bro. Sorry was not around home but I'm glad you find the solution! I see, makes sense to use the absolute URL since it won't rely on the base URL, nice one.

Answer (score 1):

you should try to call the id in p tag it may work

```
               <p id='maps'> <a class='maps'></a></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two `<a id="maps" name="maps"></a>` in your source code. Please remove one. Id's must be unique.

Comment: <a id="maps"></a> and <a name="maps"> do not work either.

Comment: <h3 id="maps">Maps &amp; Downloads</h3> does not work either.

Comment: because there is 2 ids with the same name. Which one is correct? You have two id="maps" attributes in your code. Line 272 and line 479. Remove one of them

Comment: Check your markup with W3 validator service.  https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.paulgodard.com%2Fblog%2F79

Please look at number 876

Comment: You are right. There are 2 same ids.  The reason for these 2 sets of data to be duplicated is to allow different layout for small screen and large screen.  I am using bootstrap display class for that.  So I need to find another way to do that...

Comment: I found a way to get the internal link to work as an absolute url together with the base url... and also removed the second instance of the same id